# show a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if it is closed and bounded

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Use the two lemmas to prove that a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if it is closed and bounded.

**Lemma 1:** A closed subset of a compact space is compact

**Lemma 2:** If $X$ and $Y$ are compact then $X\times Y$ is compact.

I had an idea, but that was quickly shown to be wrong by the answers in this thread

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026318/a-closed-and-bounded-subset-of-rn/1026334#1026334

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your idea from the previous thread was almost correct.

**HINT:** Show that if $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is closed and bounded, then it is a subset of some product of closed intervals (in fact, you can use the same interval!).

Comment: Sorry can you be a bit clearer on 'you can use the same interval'? Thanks

Comment: Well, your set *is* bounded, isn't it?

Comment: I'm confused now. Can you explain a bit more in symbols

Comment: please help just a bit more.

Comment: Ignore that comment about the same interval if it confuses you.